# External USB hard drive makes noises when the computer is turned off

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, shutdown, usb-drive

I have an external USB hard drive of 500GB. I can't tell what model it is exactly, as nothing specific is written on it and I don't have the box anymore. I use it as a backup disk. It works absolutely fine when the computer is turned on: no problems with writing or reading, and everything is done in dead silence.

However, if I turn the computer off and the disk is still connected, it stays on and makes clicking noises. For that reason I only connect it when I need to back up or restore. Does that mean there's a problem with the disk, or with some preferences in the system itself?

Or something else?

Disk Utility claims that SMART data is "not supported", so I don't know how to test it.

Comment: I would get a backup, and then test the drive.  It doesn't sound good.

Comment: How do I test it? The Disk Utility says that SMART data is "not supported."

Comment: You can use [Test Disk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Comment: How do I use it to run a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can not access the [S.M.A.R.T](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) data of your external drive then most likely the USB controller of your USB-drive does not support SMART commands. This may be overcome with

#### [smartmontools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/smartmontools) [image: Install smartmontools]

a tool collection designed for testing and reading SMART data that also [work on external USB drives](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki/USB).

There also is a GUI for **smartctl** [GSmartControl](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gsmartcontrol) [image: Install gsmartcontrol]

After installation these applications need to be run as root, e.g. from a terminal with

```
gksu gsmartcontrol
```

[image]

[image]

In case you encounter errors you may have an imminent disk failure ahead. If not, then you may only have a poor noise protection from your external drive case, resp. a drive that makes some noise on idle.

Comment: It seems that the quick self-test returned no errors. I'll try to run the extended self-test and see if anything is spotted. I find it hard to imagine that it's this loud when idle, and making clicking noises. Thanks for the tool, it seems to do the trick.

Comment: @AmirAdar: I have an external drive that clickers happily around when idle without any errors in the last 3 years.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I run an extended self test, and it showed no errors. I turned off my computer while the disk is connected, and it made no sound! Strange. It might make the sounds again when I turn it off the next time, but since it seems to be perfectly fine, I suppose there's no problem with that. Thank you Very much for the tools and the explanation! :)

Answer (score 0):

Test Disk can be installed from the Ubuntu Software Center.

[image]

Once installed, Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo testdisk
```

Once the program starts, maximize terminal, choose create a new log, and then choose the drive to be tested.